# Хранимые процедуры в MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server

В базе данных есть хранимые процедуры (использую ms sql 2008 r2).

> База Данных - Программирование - Хранимые процедуры.

Хочу посмотреть код хранимой процедуры, вызываю контекстное меню (правой кнопкой по процедуре), но там нет такого пункта. Есть только "Изменить". При нажатии, как я понимаю, `Create Procedure` заменяется на `Alter Procedure`. Собственно вопрос, есть ли нормальный способ посмотреть код процедуры? Надо ли каждый раз заменять `Alter Procedure` на `Create Procedure` после "просмотра" или это особо не влияет на работу процедуры?

Comment: На работу процедуры это не влияет. К сожалению, не помню как в версии 2008, а в 2014 если пункт "Script Store Procedure As" - выбираем Create - и показывается код процедуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо всего лишь посмотреть код, то какая разница, что там написано в начале, ALTER или CREATE? От того, что Вы смотрите на текст скрипта, он сам собой выполняться не будет. Более того, если Вы замените ALTER на CREATE, а потом попытаетесь выполнить скрипт, то получите ошибку примерно такого вида:

```
Сообщение 2714, уровень 16, состояние 3, процедура test, строка 2
В базе данных уже существует объект с именем "test".
```

Ну и да, как сказали выше, для не системных процедур в контекстном меню есть команда "Создать сценарий для хранимой процедуры":

[image: скриншот SSMS]

Comment: Спасибо, а если использую Изменить и случайно сохраню с `ALTER`, то что произойдет при вызове этой процедуры?

Comment: Что имеется в виду, под "случайно сохраню"? При выборе команды "Изменить" открывается окно с SQL-скриптом. Если его выполнить (F5), то он, как можно догадаться, будет выполнен. В частности, при выполнении команды ALTER PROCEDURE старый текст процедуры будет заменен на тот, который в скрипте. Если Вы там ничего не меняли, то и текст останется тем же самым. Если же вы решите именно сохранить (Ctrl-S), то получите .sql-файл на диске, с которым можете делать, что заблагорассудится. В базе же при этом ничего не изменится.

Comment: Спасибо, все прояснилось теперь

Answer (score 1):

Всю жизнь именно так и смотрю коды процедур и функций. Даже если вы Execute нажмете, ничего не произойдет, поскольку там стоит `alter`, который по сути ничего не изменит. А поскольку вы открыли только чтобы посмотреть, то вряд ли нажмете.
Так что смело жмите "Изменить"/Modify и смотрите текст.